# How to set value to property through Dozer mapping file?

Tags: dozer

I am using Dozer mapping. i have two pojo1 and pojo2. pojo1 values to be mapped to pojo2. Pojo1 has 3 properties and Pojo2 has 4 properties. i am able to map 3 properties form pojo1 to pojo2 but to map fourth property i dont have property in pojo1. to map fourth property i cannot take value from pojo1, directly i need to give the value by taking from Enum. Please help me is it possible to give value to any property through mapping file?

**value from enum directly not from pojo1**
**fourth property**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible in a convenient way. The only way to do this atm is by either having a custom converter, or by modifying one of the POJOs.

With a [custom converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html) you could just map pojo1.field3 to pojo2.field4. The converter completely ignores pojo1.field3, and just sets the pojo2.field4 to your enum value.

Another solution is to just modify pojo1 and add a field4 which always returns the enum value.

And the third solution is to modify pojo2, and just set field4 in the default constructor. If you can't modify the default constructor, you can use a [custom create method](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customCreateMethod.html) or a [custom bean factory](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custombeanfactories.html) to achieve the same.

I've been doing dozer mappings a lot, and would like some more convenient solution for this too. Unfortunately I don't think there is any atm.

Let me know how it works out for you!